# "Moved to trash" vs. "moved to the trash"

Tags: grammaticality, articles, definite-articles

Would you choose as a notification message displayed to a user on a website "your messages have been successfully moved to trash" or "... the trash"?

What is the difference and which one is more accurate?

Comment: to those who downvote: could you please explain why? I want to learn to ask better questions in the future, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a very short-format setting, such as the label to an icon, "move to trash" would be acceptable.  It's not grammatically perfect, but the need for brevity makes it acceptable.

For a longer form setting, such as the full sentences you'd find in a dialog box, I'd use the more grammatically acceptable "..moved to the trash" (or the more politically correct, "moved to the recycle bin".)